# bash script as systemd service not working as expected

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, centos

I wrote this script for my RPi3 (running CentOS 7), which is checking if someone is connected to RPi via SSH and if so, it starts another python script to turn on green LED (Blinkt!). And also it should kill the PID of python script when there is no connection. The -2 is Keyboard interrupt (CTRL+C), which is working good when testing - always turn off the LED right. But the killing part of my script is not working and I can't figure it out why.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh_status=disconnected
led_status=off

while [[ 1 == 1 ]] ; do
        netstat_ssh=`netstat -natup | grep sshd | grep -v \* | awk '{ print $6 }'`
        if [[ $netstat_ssh == ESTABLISHED ]] ; then
                ssh_status=connected
                if [[ $ssh_status == connected && $led_status == off ]] ; then
                        python /home/hlf/scripts/python/green.py
                        led_status=on
                fi
        else
                ssh_status=disconnected
                if [[ $ssh_status == disconnected && $led_status == on ]] ; then
                        blinkt=`ps -aux | grep green.py | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`
                        kill -2 $blinkt
                        led_status=off
                fi
        fi
        sleep 3
done
```

In

> /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

I have

> blinkt.service

file which contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=Blinkt

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/hlf/scripts/ssh_check.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script starts when the RPi boots up, turn on LED when I connect via SSH, but when I disconnect the LED is still on.

I'm confused.

Comment: If there's *anybody* connected via ssh, then you won't get to the "else" block. You should log the value of `netstat_ssh`

Comment: You can replace the `ps | grep | grep | awk` pipeline with `pgrep -f green.py`

Comment: you did not post your `/home/hlf/scripts/python/green.py` script. most likely it blocks - the execution of your bash script never goes past that `python /home/hlf/scripts/python/green.py` line. `python /home/hlf/scripts/python/green.py &` might help

Comment: Hmm, thats true. The python script is "while true" loop for keeping the LED active. So backgrounding it might help the bash script continue. Thanks for your point, will try tommorow.